# trouble understanding passing 2d array to methods and displaying

Tags: java, arrays, methods

With this program I am supposed to use methods to pass through to obtain user input to fill a 3x4 2d array. Then add the sum of the columns and display the results.

The int[][] grid = fillArray(); has an error that in[][] required. Why am I unable to call my method in the main? This is how the book says to do it along witih countless youtube videos.

```
public class SumOfColumns {

    

    public static int sumColumn(int[][] m, int columnIndex) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++) {
            columnIndex = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                columnIndex += m[column][row];
            }
        }
        return columnIndex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       ***int[][] grid = fillArray();***
    }
    public static int[][] fillArray(int[][] userInput) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int[][] grid = new int[3][4];
        System.out.println("Enter a 3x4 grid of numbers please: ");
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                grid[row][column] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare your `fillArray` function you gave it an input of `int[][] userInput`, but then when you call:

```
int[][] grid = fillArray();
```

you don't give `fillArray` and input of `int[][]`. If you remove the paramter from the `fillArray` function that should fix it. It would look like:

```
public static int[][] fillArray() {
    // your code...
}
```